# MVC5 Delete button error code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working in MVC5.  I have a functioning .mdf in dbContext.  It produces data in the following table.  The Delete button prints out but gives the error below when pressed:

Index.cshtml

```
<center>
<table>
    <tr><td align="center">testID</td><td align="center">datetime</td><td align="center">col1</td><td align="center">col2</td><td align="center">col3</td><td></td></tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.thistable)
    {
        <tr><td>@item.testID</td><td>@item.datetime</td><td>@item.col1</td><td>@item.col2</td><td>@item.col3</td><td><form action="@Url.Action("Delete", new{ testID = @item.testID})" method="delete"><input type="submit" value="Delete" /></form></td></tr>
    }
</table>
</center>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private testContext db = new testContext();
    private UserViewModel uvm = new UserViewModel();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Table1> thattable = db.Data1.ToList();
            uvm.thistable = thattable;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            uvm.errorcode = ex.ToString();
        }

        return View(uvm);
    }
    public ActionResult Delete(int testID)
    {
        uvm.thistable.Remove(uvm.thistable.SingleOrDefault(o => o.testID == testID));
        db.SaveChanges(); 
        return View();
    }

public class Table1
{
    [Key]
    public int testID { get; set; }
    public string datetime { get; set; }
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
    public string col3 { get; set; }
}
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string errorcode { get; set; }
    public List<Table1> thistable { get; set; }
}
public class testContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Table1> Data1 { get; set; }
}
```

}

Error code:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'testID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Delete(Int32)' in 'MDFtoMVCdelete.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no record at the record in which you are attempting to delete

Comment: I have the records I just did not list them.  ReCheck above post.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
   public ActionResult Delete(int testID)
    {
        var toDel = uvm.thistable.Where(or => or.testId == testID).FirstOrDefault();
        if(toDel != null)
        {
          uvm.thistable.Remove(toDel);
          db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: uvm.thistable.Remove(uvm.thistable.Find(testID)); produces an error at Find.

Comment: The error is with "uvm.thistable.Find(testID)".  TestID does not match List<Table1>.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that 'testID' isn't getting passed into the Action. I believe that the query string on a Url is ignored unless its a GET so that could be why testID isn't being passed. It is complaining because you are using an `int` as your Action parameter and none is being passed. Try including an input that has the `testID` so that it includes the `testID` in the response body instead of the querystring.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Delete"))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="testID" value="@item.testID" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
}
```

This will actually use the POST form method instead of DELETE form method but unless there is a specific reason you want to use the DELETE method, POST should be fine.

Also, you should probably decorate the `Delete` ActionMethod with the `[HttpPost]` attribute so it cannot be called with a GET.